# { Error: [React Intl Error MISSING_DATA] Missing locale data for locale: "th" in Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: react-intl

I've checked this source https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl#runtime-requirements , and tried to add this code

```
import { NumberFormat } from '@formatjs/intl-numberformat'

NumberFormat.__addLocaleData(
  require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/dist/locale-data/en.json') // locale-data for en
)

NumberFormat.__addLocaleData(
  require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/dist/locale-data/th.json') // locale-data for th
)
```

But it doesn't help, also I've added `defaultLocale` param :

```
<IntlProvider defaultLocale={locale}></IntlProvider>
```

to intl provider , but it also doesn't help. I have 2 languages , for `en` language I don't get this error , only for `th` language , what should I do ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you mange to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrade your Node Version. I had 10 and moved to 14.x: Issue was gone

Comment: THANK YOU Jan! I searched for hours to find the root of this strange error message. My app worked completely fine, but this error message kept bothering me. The node.js update solved it for me. Thank you again! You completely made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the object being utilized.

Check the object structure of translation content.

`IntlProvider` should have `messages` property whose value should be an object which contains property mentioned in `id` of `FormattedMessage`